# How to get current post type in functions.php in order to use globally?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I want to check the post type of any pages or posts and display some features depending on the post type. So I'm using a function in functions.php which returns the post type when used in admin pages but not on theme pages.

I need this function to include a php file if the post type is `page`. So it must work system wide (if it's possible). In templates, admin, edit and post pages.

Here is the function that I'm using:

```
function vart_current_post_type() {
    global $post, $typenow, $current_screen;

    if ( $post && $post->post_type ) {
        return $post->post_type;
    }

    elseif ( isset( $_GET[ 'post' ] ) ) {
        return get_post_type( $_GET[ 'post' ] );
    }

    elseif ( $typenow ) {
        return $typenow;
    }

    elseif ( $current_screen && $current_screen->post_type ) {
        return $current_screen->post_type;
    }

    elseif ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'post_type' ] ) ) {
        return sanitize_key( $_REQUEST[ 'post_type' ] );
    }

    return null;
}

add_action( 'init', 'vart_current_post_type' );
```

Please tell me what should I do in order to make it work on theme templates and pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a native method to find out current post type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
```

Comment: When you use this method in page.php or index.php it's working fine but I need to get the post type in functions.php which returns null.

Comment: Yes I need to get the post type info whenever I need it. I don't know if it's possible though :)

Comment: Try finding first hook where this method is available.

Comment: Any Solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

On the `init` hook, the `$post` object is not yet populated.

See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for WP hook (action) execution. As you can see, posts are selected much later after init. To be more precise, even the request is parsed after init hook. So there is no easy way to get post type in init action, I'm afraid.

With the `wp` hook you can get the post type with your function.